# How to stop scrolling in mat-drawer-content, when mat-sidenav is opened

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8, sidenav, mat-sidenav

Am using angular material version 8.x. in my application. Have used mat-sidenav-container. When I open the menu, the mat-drawer-content is also getting scroll-able and upon scrolling it to bottom or top, the side menu(mat-sidenav) is getting close. is there any fix available for this.